# Align text and tick mark in Digital signature iText

Tags: java, itext

1. I am using `appearance.setAcro6Layers(false); //depricated` to show the tick mark. Is there any other way to display tick mark.

There is a text displaying on top of the signature.

2. I want to change the size and style of the text and
3. size of the green tick mark.

   ```
       PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();      
       appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, reader.getNumberOfPages(), "Signature Box");
       appearance.setReason(Constants.REASON);
       appearance.setLocation(Constants.LOCATION);
       appearance.setLayer4Text(Constants.LAYER4TEXT);
       appearance.setLayer2Font(font);
      appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
   ```
4. AND Layer 2 text is aligned to the right side. Is there a chance to adjust the alignment?

[image]

Comment: Signature state visualizations like that tick mark were deprecated more than 10 years ago. Thus, the only non-deprecated way to display a tick mark there is by making it part of the regular appearance (so that it always is displayed).

Comment: That being said, you can always explicitly draw the layers yourself, simply retrieve the layer template and design it. What you have now merely is the old iText default appearance of those layers.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391641/1729265

Comment: thanks, @mkl for your response